# how can I get this a tag to go to the link exluding the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an awesome animation that runs on page startup/entry but when I actually get to use the page and all the stuff in the website I want to have a tag that goes back to the index.html page WITHOUT the cool animation... It will only upset people using the website. Here is the tag:

```
<a href="index.html"><div id="logo-title"></div></a>
```

and here is the code I want the link to remove when clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit, #logo, #wrapper").hide("slow"); 
       $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 10000);

 });
```

**How do I get rid of the code when the link is clicked for the same page?**

Comment: can you  give us a fiddle to see the animation and look closely how it works

Comment: having trouble with jsfiddle atm but in terms of the animation , its just a couple of divs that hang around for 10 seconds  , is there any way to bypass this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your solution, check it out here: http://transitiontest.comeze.com/test4/index.html

To achieve this you need to use `document.referrer` to check what page the user came from. If this page is the same as the one he is currently viewing, the animation will not play.

In your case this would look like:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var referrer =  document.referrer;

    if (referrer == "............/index.html") {
        // Do stuff     
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit, #logo, #wrapper").hide("slow"); 
            $("#wrapper").unwrap();
        }, 10000);

});
```

Comment: thanks for the response mate ... the trouble is that the code resides on the intro of the actual index.html page itself.... so basically intro happens , then button with index is presented , if you click on that it should take you to the same page but this time without the animation.

Comment: Well isn't that the same case here: http://transitiontest.comeze.com/test4/ ? Intro happens, link shows up. This redirects you to the same page but without the animation.

Comment: ... so basically the example works but only if the link is present , the intro still needs to run on the first time

Comment: But it does right, the animation runs when you load [the page](http://transitiontest.comeze.com/test4/) for the first time.

Comment: hmmm , maybe i am missing something because the animation intro runs but in loop so it doesn't complete after the 10 seconds and "hide/unwrap"... it is at this point that you get to see the a tag , ... #iamawkward

Comment: well you gave the right answer to the question so vote up for you sir , I do wonder How I might be able to allow the animation to run once on first time but after that no more animation .. hmmm

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.codedisqus.com/0SxqkgeUUX/run-css3-animation-only-once-at-page-loading.html) link.

Comment: interesting stuff so basically using this animation-iteration-count: 1 somehow would solve my problem

Comment: awesome sorry i missed your messages , lets chat tomorrow if ya have time , happy to share the source with you mate